# Css + html: Image relative with text over it

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Since a few days I am trying to make this work. I have a design with an image with a `text` over it, I just finally could set the text over the image, but I want to give a `top position` to the image but too much space at the bottom and I don't know how to fix it!

This is what I have: I know I have to fix some `padding` things on the texts.

[image]

and this is my markup, by the way I am using `bootstrap`.

```
<div class="row-color clearfix">
<div class="container">
<div class="col-lg-12 no-padding wrapper">
<img class="img-responsive" src="http://s12.postimg.org/mu9u7nzvx/header_ml_02.png" alt="">
<div id="bg-text">
<div class="text-overimg">Child Education Planner</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="texto_cursos">Face courses, distance and on-line</div>
</div>
</div>



.row-color {
    background: #575756 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.no-padding {
    padding:0px;
}

.wrapper {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}

.wrapper .img-responsive {
    display:inline;
}

.wrapper #bg-text {
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}

.text-overimg{
    position:relative;
    font-size:3.1em;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:500;
    text-shadow: 0.08em 0.08em 0.05em #333;
    padding-top: 20%;
}

.texto_cursos{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    font-size:2.5em;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:400;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I would like to have this, I have to say that I want to make it responsive for most of the devices, this is one of the things I use `bootstrap`.

This is what I really want to have but don't know how to do it. Specially the white `background` behind the image without too much space between the last text and the image.

[image]

Thanks again!

Comment: Your question is not clear enough...Also, your code is really messy and your css logic is on the ground.

Comment: Hi, sorry if I was not very clear. That´s why I attached two pictures, the first image is what I have now, and the second one what I want. Just want to give some top to the image and avoid the brown box get longer in height.

Comment: put complete html and css .. try creating a jsfiddle.

Comment: in that case.. try giving margin-top to grey box.

Comment: Give margin-top to the wrapper div and margin-top with minus to the image. That's one of the solutions. I don't understand what's that hard that you had to post it here.

Comment: Hi Era, this is the html and css, the other classes like clearfix, container, col-lg-12 and img-responsive are from bootstrap. I think can be attached to the jsfiddle like this : @import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

Comment: Hi lonut, I tried with this before, but when I resize the browser the text inside the image doesn't fixed on it.

Comment: @user2112420, add a margin bottom to the image too, beside what I said.

Comment: Thanks lonut, this resolve part of my problem, I will have to change by css the margins for the wraper and image in the differents devices, because I want it responsive.

Comment: if you look at my answer you can see a working example with your code. You can copy it and use it. If it helps you then please upvote my answer and accept it as an answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

** UPDATE I Accidently said if you want to move the image up a little. I meant down**

If you want to move the image down a little you can add a `margin-top` to it:

```
.wrapper .img-responsive {
    display:inline;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

Please see [**JSFiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/t1k2xvgt/)

Answer (score -1):

try something like that:

```css
.imagebox-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.imagebox img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
.imagebox-caption {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.imagebox {
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.imagebox-caption-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  transition: 500ms all linear;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: transparent;
  color: white;
}

.imagebox:hover .imagebox-caption-overlay {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagebox-container">
  <div class="imagebox">
    <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/header_1.png" />
    <div class="imagebox-caption-overlay">ANOTHER BLA BLA BLA</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="imagebox-caption">
    bla bla bla
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -3):

may be you need this. please see .

```css
.imagebox-container {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(0, gray 50%, transparent 50%);
}
.imagebox img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
.imagebox-caption {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagebox-container">
  <div class="imagebox">
   <img class="img-responsive" src="http://s12.postimg.org/mu9u7nzvx/header_ml_02.png" alt="">
  </div>
  
  <div class="imagebox-caption">
   Face courses, distance and on-line
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you've copied my answer :D!
Bad!